# achartengine time chart set initial range

Tags: android, achartengine

**SOLUTION**

Instead of using `setInitialRange()` I had to set the initial x-values using `setXAxisMin()` as well as `setXAxisMax()`. A little bit confusing, I think.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I'm currently working on a project involving the acharteninge library for drawing time diagrams which works excellent so far. The user is capable of switching between various graphs (one XYMultipleSeriesDataset plus one TimeSeries per graph) via separate buttons. So far, achartengine displays all x values when the graph is shown.

However, I was asked to display only the data captured in the first three hours when the graph is shown, as this information is most relevant. Nevertheless, the user should still be able to scroll to data captured after the first three hours meaning that limiting the x-axis maximum value is not an option.

For example: There are two curves. The first curve is drawn using data captured over a period of 4 hours, while the second curve is created out of data captured over 18 hours.

In the current version my programme initially displays all data of the graph which gets displayed meaning the first curve shows three hours of very relevant data while 1 hour of not so important information is shown too. The "ratio" of the second curve is 3 to 15 (highly significant data vs regular data). As a result, a different amount of high important information is shown when the user compares the two curves making it harder for the user to compare this data, as he has to adjust the zoom manually.

**EDIT 01.04.2015 15:46**

For setting the initial range I use the XYMultipleSeriesRenderer instance's method `setInitialRange(double[] initialRange);` which does not affect the graph at all. Below you can see my statement (`currentlyProcessedCurve.getRecordStart()` is an instance of Joda's DateTime and furhtermore it's the x value of the first displayed point):

```
public static final int CHART_X_AXIS_INITIAL_MAX = 3;
public static final int CHART_MARGIN_PAN = 45;
...
double[] initialRange = { currentlyProcessedCurve.getRecordStart().minusMinutes(ApplicationSettings.CHART_MARGIN_PAN).toDate().getTime(), currentlyProcessedCurve.getRecordStart().plusHours(ApplicationSettings.CHART_X_AXIS_INITIAL_MAX).toDate().getTime(), 0, 600 };
currentDatasetRenderer.setInitialRange(initialRange);
```

**TIDE (Edit end)**

The screenshot below approximately shows how the curve should look initially (Just for making it clear: Please only consider the graphs' shapes, as they should look equal --> What I'm trying to say: I know that the x-axis and the y-axis label of the two screenshots different, but I don't have better pictures yet):

[desired initial range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Js3VP.png)

Finally, the following screenshot shows how the curve looks when displayed:

[image: current initial range]

For enabling the user to compare the curves I have locked the y-axis zoom.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `XYMultipleSeriesRendererInstance.setInitialRange()` I had to set the initial x-values using `XYMultipleSeriesRendererInstance.setXAxisMin()` as well as `XYMultipleSeriesRendererInstance.setXAxisMax()`.

```
double xMinValue = ...;
double xMaxValue = ...;
currentDatasetRenderer.setXAxisMin(xMinValue);
currentDatasetRenderer.setXAxisMax(xMaxValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you consider pan option?

With this option you can limit axis maximum, and your chart will show the important data on start, while user can scroll left or right (wherever you have less important data points).

All you need to do is:

- set pan enabled for axis you need
- set pan limits (so user can't scroll past the last data point)

Hope this helps,
Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, using pan has definitely improved my programme, as the user is not able to scroll into the diagram's "nirvana" anymore. However, the inital range of the chart has not changed yet. For doing this I have discovered the method setInitialRange of the XYMultipleSeries instance. Nevertheless, this method does not seem to affetct the graph, although the developer's have already fixed such a problem (https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/issues/detail?id=60).